# How to enable debugging on Chrome on Android device?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging

I used to debug my apps by connecting my phone to the PC. But now I can't. Everything because when I unblock Developer Options (by clicking few times on About Chrome/Application Version) on Chrome on my phone and then go to Developers Options. There is only one option: Tracing.

What happened? I used to go there six month ago to select "**allow debugging**". But now all those options are gone. And not only on my phone, but also two other and one tablet.

Two Sony phones: Android 9 Chrome 89.0.4

Samsung phone: Android 5.0.1 Chrome 89.0.4

Tablet Samsung Android 6.0.1 Chrome 89.0.4

[image]

Because I can't select "allow debugging" my Chrome Browser on PC doesn't see the phone.

Does it happen only to me?
I can't find **anyone** having the same problem. But the "only one option" problem appears on my three different devices.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out there are two "Developer Options". One in a Chrome Browser and second on Android itself and I was unlocking the wrong one, on a browser, instead on an Android. Who could think there are two "Developer Options".

The right places to click are:

Android 9 (API level 28) and higher: Settings > About Phone > Build Number

Android 8.0.0 (API level 26) and Android 8.1.0 (API level 26): Settings > System > About Phone > Build Number

Android 7.1 (API level 25) and lower: Settings > About Phone > Build Number

**AND NOT IN CHROME: Settings > About Chrome > Application version**